# Which Ceph OSD is mapped to which pysical drive

Tags: linux, ceph

I have a Ceph system with 8 OSD's and 8 disks mapped 1:1.

One of the disks is giving me smart errors and I would like to replace it.

How do I know which physical disk is mapped to which OSD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ceph device ls` (alternatively `ceph device ls-by-host <host>` or by daemon) to see the mapping of host, OSD and device, including block.db devices in cases you have the rocksDB/WAL on faster devices.

Answer (score 0):

The command `ceph-volume lvm list` displays all the OSD's with the corresponding devices.

See https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/man/8/ceph-volume/#list for more information.

> List devices or logical volumes associated with Ceph. An association
> is determined if a device has information relating to an OSD. This is
> verified by querying LVM’s metadata and correlating it with devices.
>
> The lvs associated with the OSD need to have been prepared previously
> by ceph-volume so that all needed tags and metadata exist.
>
> Usage:
>
> `ceph-volume lvm list`
>
> List a particular device, reporting all metadata about it:
>
> `ceph-volume lvm list /dev/sda1`
>
> List a logical volume, along with all its metadata (vg is a volume
> group, and lv the logical volume name):
>
> `ceph-volume lvm list {vg/lv}`

Comment: You can also use `ceph device ls` to see the mapping of host, OSD and device, including block.db devices in cases you have the rocksDB/WAL on faster devices.

Comment: @eblock you are totally right! If you could create an answer with this I can accept it as a solution.